# Could not convert variant of type (Unknown) into type (Dispatch)

Tags: iis-7, inno-setup, pascalscript

I´m trying to port the following javascript code to inno-setup pascal script:

```
var adminManager = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AdminManager');
var appPoolsSection = adminManager.GetAdminSection('system.applicationHost/applicationPools', 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST');
var appPoolsCollection = applicationPoolsSection.Collection;
for (var i = 0; i < appPoolsCollection.Count; i++)
{
    var appPool = appPoolsCollection.Item(i);
    // doing someting with the application pool
}
```

This code has been translated to this:

```
var AdminManager, AppPoolsSection, AppPoolsCollection, AppPool: Variant;
    i: Integer;
begin
  AdminManager := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AdminManager');
  AppPoolsSection := AdminManager.GetAdminSection('system.applicationHost/applicationPools', 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST');
  AppPoolsCollection := AppPoolsSection.Collection;
  for i := 0 to AppPoolsCollection.Count-1 do begin
    AppPool := AppPoolsCollection.Item(i);
    // doing someting with the application pool
  end;
end;
```

But it is raising the following error on line `AppPoolsCollection := AppPoolsSection.Collection`:

```
Exception: Could not convert variant of type (Unknown) into type (Dispatch).
```

There are any thing that I can do to inform to pascal scritp that the `AppPoolsSection` object is an `IDispach` and not only an `IUnknown`?

Comment: Your [`IAppHostAdminManager::GetAdminSection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965186(v=vs.90).aspx) method call looks somehow strange to me. It should have 3 parameters, where the 3rd one would be the `AppPoolsSection` variable and the result of type `HRESULT`. It seems your code failed on passing `HRESULT` value to the `AppPoolsSection` variable assuming it's a collection later on.

Comment: It was a direct port of the javascript example from [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites). I´ll trey it using the interfaces declarations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that works and is simpler than "import" the interfaces definition.

All the COM components used in this code implements IDispatch (it is required to use on VBScript or JScript), then I imported the [VariantChangeType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to cast the IUnknown reference to an IDispatch reference (as it appears not to be supported on pascal script).

Follow the final code:

```
function VariantChangeType(out Dest: Variant; Source: Variant; Flags, vt: Word): HRESULT; external 'VariantChangeType@oleaut32.dll stdcall';

function VarToDisp(Source: Variant): Variant;
begin
  Result := Unassigned;
  OleCheck(VariantChangeType(Result, Source, 0, varDispatch));
end; 

procedure EnumerateAppPools(AppPools: TStrings);
var AdminManager, Section, Collection, Item, Properties: Variant;
    i: Integer;
begin
  AdminManager := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.ApplicationHost.AdminManager');
  Section := VarToDisp(AdminManager.GetAdminSection('system.applicationHost/applicationPools', 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'));
  Collection := VarToDisp(Section.Collection);
  for i := 0 to Collection.Count-1 do begin
    Item := VarToDisp(Collection.Item(i));
    Properties := VarToDisp(Item.Properties);
    if (VarToDisp(Properties.Item('managedPipelineMode')).Value = 1) and 
       (VarToDisp(Properties.Item('managedRuntimeVersion')).Value = 'v4.0') then
      AppPools.Add(VarToDisp(Properties.Item('name')).Value);
  end;
end;
```